# Cannot turn on Wifi or Bluetooth

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

I have a Galaxy Tab 4 SM-T230, but for some reason it will not turn on WiFi or Bluetooth. The slider goes green for 2 seconds then turns itself off.

I have Googled this problem and it would appear it is a common problem, but for the life of me I can not find a solution.

I have:

- done a full hard reset
- performed a restore from files saved in December
- started tablet up in safe mode
- I have removed the 32 GB memory card and powered down the device then started the device up without the memory card

Despite all this, the Wifi and Bluetooth do not work. I am beginning to think this is a hardware problem rather than a software issue and assistance appreciated.

Comment: You have another device that works with that wifi?

Answer (score 1):

As an update I contacted Samsung, as the tablet is in warranty, and they told me that the only solution is to take the tablet into their repair centre in the city. As it needs to be flashed with new firmware.

Having done that, they have now told me that the tablet requires some parts as there is an issue with this model. Unsure what parts are needed but will post a reply once I collect the tablet and get the repair report from Samsung. There is no damage to the tablet as it is only 8 weeks old